# Spring boot custom user profile url

Tags: spring-boot

How do I implement a unique URL for each user created?

I have my user class set to create the columns "Id, Username, Email, First, Last name and address"

How would I tell spring boot to generate an address based on the username upon account creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don’t. You do it yourself. You have to create an endpoint accepting a path parameter (which in your case would be “username”). With that parameter you can do whatever is expected given the corresponding HTTP method (get, update, delete, etc). For additional details refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable.

Additionally, you can also take a look at Spring Boot Data REST, which can also serve your purpose with even less. Ode by creating the controller layer for you. For additional details refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro.